# Converting X Y coords to Lat Long Equirectangular projecton C++

Tags: c++, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Hi all creating a new program am im using a Equirectangular Projection of the planet earth. The user gets to move the map around zoom in and out etc the normal stuff.

I have hit a bit of a stop trying to work out how to convert my X(21600 Pixels) by y(10800 Pixels) to a Latitude and Longitude.

I have been reading up on some of the  ways to convert it into Lat Long and my brain has just melted , my math skills arnt great still learning at what not.

If you need more info i can give a link to my GitHub repository to view all the code at once.

A section of code to make it work would be ace, but learning experience could you maybe explain how it works and the conversions and what not.

Thanks very much all;

Comment: To understand better your needs: you want to display a map with objects identified by their coordinates. To do so you need a way to tell "this stuff at Lat XX/Long YY goes _there_ on my screen". Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's *Equirectangular Projection* your `(x, y)` coordinates map directly to longitude and latitude.  All you need to do is scale them, something like:

```
longitude = x * longitude_per_pixel;
latitude  = y * latitude_per_pixel;
```

Comment: When your posting a answer make it more clear what these varibles are, i mean if i saw this where does this magic long_per_pixel come from, and what does it mean?-- But thanks anyway for the post man, i just literally solved the problem as you posted this aha

Comment: @JakeWade that's really your side of things, I'm showing the basic direction forwards.  But I can't read your mind and see all the details in front of you and move your hands to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now very simple formula to work out X Y coords to Lat Long

"Coded using the QT complier"

I used a QGraphicsView widget, then placed an scene inside of that with the image my the world.

Then using doing this to create the exact value of your X and Y

```
//make this in your initalizer
//this gets the exact value of the scene you are using
double map_height{0}
double map_width{0}
map_height = ui->m_graphicsview->scene()->height();
map_width = ui->m_graphicsview->scene()->width();

then create a mouse_event -  and set the mouse_move
set 2 varibles like this
double x = mouse_event->pos(); //This isnt exact but you get the idea
double y = moue_event->pos();

then using these two varibles call up a function

double getLat(double x)
{
   double lon =(x * 360) /(m_map_width)-180;
   return lon;
}
double getLon(double y)
{
double lat = (y * 180) / (m_map_height)-90;
return lat;
}
```

very simple, if you would like to view my GitHub repo please message me

Comment: I think you flipped content of the getLat and getLon functions?!